# A topological space with cofinite topology is Hausdorff iff it's finite?

Tags: general-topology

It can be proved that if a topological space with cofinite topology is Hausdorff then it's finite. For instance see [drhab's post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954031/the-real-line-and-finite-complement-topology-is-not-a-hausdorff). I was wondering whether the converse is also true? That's if $X$ is finite then $\{x\}, \{y\}$ are open sets and $\{x\}\cap \{y\}=\emptyset$ for any $x,y \in X, x\ne y$. Thus $X$ is Hausdorff. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct - the key point of course being that $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ are open since the whole space is finite, so the complement of *any* set is finite; that is, the cofinite topology on a finite set is **discrete**.